# Remove item from array if it already exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm adding ids to an array by checking a list of checkboxes which have unique ids. I want to remove the id from the array if a user clicks on the checkbox again (uncheck). How to remove the id from the array if the id already exists?

This is the function i've written to add the ids to an array

```
    addEvcToArray(id) {
        const stationId = {
            stationId: id
        }
        var evcIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
        this.setState({ stationIdArray: evcIdArray })
    }
```

With the current system,if the user clicks on the checkbox again, the id related to the checkbox is added again.

Comment: you want the same function for adding and removing the id to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findIndex` to see if an index with that `stationId` exists. If so, `slice` both ends of the array to the left and right of that index to create a new array without that element:

```
addEvcToArray(id) {
  const { stationIdArray } = this.state;
  const index = stationIdArray.findIndex(({ stationId }) => stationId === id);
  if (index === -1) {
    this.setState({
      stationIdArray: [...stationIdArray, { stationId: id }]
    });
  } else {
    const slicedArr = [...stationIdArray.slice(0, index), ...stationIdArray.slice(index + 1)];
    this.setState({
      stationIdArray: slicedArr
    });
  }
}
```

Or, less repetitively, using the conditional operator:

```
addEvcToArray(id) {
  const { stationIdArray } = this.state;
  const index = stationIdArray.findIndex(({ stationId }) => stationId === id);
  const newStationArray = index === -1
    ? [...stationIdArray, { stationId: id }]
    : [...stationIdArray.slice(0, index), ...stationIdArray.slice(index + 1)];
  this.setState({
    stationIdArray: newStationArray
  });
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the slice (I think I read splice in your post but I may be wrong). Anyway, splice is detected by [vue](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)

Comment: @grodzi OP is using react. `splice` should be avoided, because it mutates the existing array. `slice` should be used instead, since it doesn't mutate.

Comment: So dumb, not even able to read tags, sorry for that (I even answerd to a post of op using setState minutes ago...)

Comment: IMHO, as `slice` has minimal performances impact vs `filter`, I would using `filter`, because is more readable and it's easier to reason about

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the item exists or not, and then add or remove the item.

To remove an item from an array you can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
  addEvcToArray(id) {
    const { stationIdArray } = this.state;
    const index = stationIdArray.findIndex(({ stationId }) => stationId === id);
    if (index === -1) { //not found, add
      this.setState({ stationIdArray: [...stationIdArray, { stationId: id }]});
    } else { //already exists, remove
      const updatedArray = stationIdArray.filter(s => s.stationId !== id)
      this.setState({stationIdArray: updatedArray});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element exist, otherwise filter it out from your array before setting it again in state:

```
function addEvcToArray(id) {
  const stationId = {
    stationId: id,
  };
  if (
    !this.state.stationArray.find(element => element.stationId === id) // returns the object otherwise undefined
  ) {
    const evcIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
    this.setState({ stationIdArray: evcIdArray });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      stationIdArray: stationIdArray.filter(
        element => element.stationId !== stationId, // returns an array with all values except current stationId
      ),
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
addEvcToArray(id) {
         let newArr=[]
        const { stationIdArray } = this.state;
        let filtered = stationIdArray.filter(filt=> filt.stationId!==id)
          newArr = [...filtered , {stationId:id}];

        this.setState({ stationIdArray: newArr})
    }
```